# Остановка выполнения цикла while

Tags: comet, while, php, sleep, long-poll

Всем привет! Интересует вопрос - как можно правильно остановить выполнение while цикла со sleep внутри. 
Дело в том, что я реализовываю "**long poll**" для быстрого обновления информации на сайте (оповещения, другая информация).

**СУТЬ РАБОТЫ СКРИПТА**

**1.** Мы отправляем GET-запрос на PHP-страницу в которой расположен скрипт.

**2.** Скрипт запускает цикл **while**.

**3.** В данном цикле существует **2** условия и sleep(1) в конце, который приостанавливает выполнение цикла.

**-** Если если цикл работает больше **30** секунд - **останавливаем** выполнение цикла, соответственно и скрипта.

**-** Если на сайте появилась новая информация, скажем "оповещение" - **выводим** результат пользователю и **останавливаем** цикл.

**ПРОБЛЕМА** 
Если пользователь закроет окно браузера, или же перезагрузит страницу - выполнится новый запрос на данный скрипт, который запустит цикл повторно. Но при этом, предыдущие выполнение  цикла **while не остановятся**, пока не сработает хотя бы одно условие внутри него. Если же пользователь отошлет много запросов на страницу - память сервера начинает сильно грузится и в результате все висит, пока все **while** не остановят свое выполнение.

**ВОПРОС** 
Как остановить выполнение цикла и скрипта в целом при повторном выполнении или же перезагрузке страницы клиентом? 
Пока на данный момент я сделал следующее.
При выполнении скрипта мы генерируем рандомное число, которое записываем в переменную и так же с сессию. Далее внутри while делаю условие, в котором данная переменная должна равняться значению сессии. Если false - останавливаем цикл. 
Если мы запускаем скрипт по новой - значение сессии меняется и соответственно все предыдущие выполнения while останавливаются. 
Можно ли использовать такой вариант? И на сколько он безопасен?

**UPDATE.PHP**

```
 // инициализируем сессию пользователя
 $session = Session::instance();

        $rand = rand();
        $session->set('user_update_key', $rand);
        $key = $rand;

        $limit = 20;
        $seconds = 0;

        set_time_limit($limit + 1);

        while (TRUE) {
            if (Session::instance()->get('user_update_key') == $key) {

                if (есть ли обновления. если есть - выводим) {
                    echo 'информация обновлений';
                    flush();
                    exit;
                }
                if ($seconds == $limit) { // завершаем выполнение цикла по истечению времени.
                    echo 'Close';
                    flush();
                    exit;
                }
                $seconds++;
            } else {
                unset($session, $rand, $key, $notice, $mysession, $last_notice, $limit, $notise_return, $seconds);
                flush();
                exit;
            }
            session_write_close();
            sleep(1);
            session_start();
```

}

Comment: А если злонамеренный пользователь сгенерирует дофига запросов с одним и тем же значением переменной?

Comment: Переменная ведь генерируется в самом файле php. 
Я не говорю, что тут все хорошо. Мне и саму не нравится данная реализация. 
В идеале сделать вот так - пользователь закрыл страницу, или обновил - все, скрипт остановился. Но так не получается(

Answer (score 4):

Похоже, вас интересует двусторонняя коммуникация пользователя с долгоиграющим процессом на PHP, и процессов PHP между собой во время их исполнения. PHP под это не заточен, как уже писали, но есть [расширения](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/refs.fileprocess.process.php), которые могут оказаться полезными.

Без дополнительных примочек подходит механизм сессий, или же похожий собственный, задействующий, например, БД как "общую память". В первом приближении, я бы сделал точно то же, что и вы.

Почему вы хотите именно long polling, а не новый разовый запрос раз в секунду? VK виджеты для комментариев, скажем, именно так работают. Если веб сервер настроен не закрывать мгновенно каждое соединение, то цепочка таких запросов не станет тормозить. (См. настройку [KeepAlive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive) для Apache)

Наконец, можно посомтреть в сторону других технологий и протоколов, напр. Flash и RTMP: маленькая флешка в веб странице, которая по RTMP связывается с сервером [RED5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), и получает/отправляет инфу через JS коммуникацию с флешкой - настоящий риалтайм!

Comment: @sergiks вместо `rtmp` желательно использовать `websockets`, дабы они и во флеше есть и в html5.

Comment: @lampa спасибо, будду знать.

Answer (score 2):

Поищите другие варианты - как раз недавно на Хабре была [статья о природе и ограничениях PHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/). В комментариях предлагаются и другие варианты. Например, [в этом](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/#comment_6229367) и [в этом](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/#comment_6227939).

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант, записать время в куки , и недавать юзеру выполнять следующий запрос пока тот не выполнится......

Comment: Ок. А если пользователь начнет через консоль писать свой js с циклом ajax. 
Пусто

Comment: и что это даст ?

Comment: Это даст то, что если пользователь вручную запустит 100 запросов на скрипт - запустится 100 while и сервер убьется.

Comment: Запиши тогда в базу